# How can I change the color of my scatter plot points based on a "color" column in my dataset in plotly (python)?

Tags: python, animation, plotly

I have this code which animates NFL tracking data using plotly. I would like to be able to manually change the color of the home/away team and the ball. I have tried using the code below however it all comes in the same color. I have a column in my dataset called "color" which I would like to be used to assign the color to each individual data point.

```
# SCATTER TO ANIMATE TRACKING DATA 
fig = px.scatter(data,  x = "x", y = "y", hover_name="displayName",
          color="color", animation_frame = "frameId", animation_group = "displayName",
          range_y = [-5, 60], range_x = [-5, 125])

fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 80


for i in range(0, 121, 10):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[i,i], y=[0,53.3], mode='lines', line=dict(color='white'), showlegend=False))
    
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(zeroline=False, showgrid=False), 
                  yaxis=dict(zeroline=False, showgrid=False))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0,120], y=[0,0], mode='lines', line=dict(color='white'), showlegend=False))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0,120], y=[53.3,53.3], mode='lines', line=dict(color='white'), showlegend=False))

#fig.write_html("football.html")

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=600
)

fig
```

Here is a sample of the data:

| x | y | team | color | frameId | displayName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61.21 | 46.77 | home | Green | 1 | Mahomes |
| 60 | 32 | away | black | 1 | Beckham |

And a photo of what I currently have:

[Picture of the updated figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOYiF.png) (If you look at the right the label names don't match the colors I want)

Comment: Please share some sample data in text format (not picture)

Comment: I think this question will benefit from a picture. You can insert a picture file using the toolbar at the top of the text entry window, or press Ctrl-G.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips, I hahve added some sample data and a picture of the figure I currently have

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. Your photo of your figure exactly shows what you are describing wanting?

Comment: Oh yeah woops that’s my bad, I should’ve changed the colors in the sample data, those on the figure are just the colors plotly gives me

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it, I had to set `color = "team"` and then `color_discrete_map`. The code that works is:

```
fig = px.scatter(data,  x = "x", y = "y", hover_name="displayName",
          color="team", animation_frame = "frameId", animation_group = "displayName",
          range_y = [-5, 60], range_x = [-5, 125], color_discrete_map = dict((["home", "black"], ["away", "red"], ["football", "brown"])))
```